# asp.net login redirecting to wrong page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, login-control

We have an asp.net site with a membership area. The owner wanted to update the public portion of the site with a new look, so I created a new login page with the new look, but the same code. Put the page in the same directory as the original login.aspx, but called it new_login.aspx. Tested the new page and it works from my development computer but when tested from other computers redirects the user to a non-existant page.

The code that is on both pages is as follows.

```
   Protected Sub LoginButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim sUser As String = Me.New_Login.UserName
        If Roles.IsUserInRole(sUser, "Administrator") Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Manager/AMSEmployees.aspx")
        ElseIf Roles.IsUserInRole(sUser, "Manager") Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Manager/AMSEmployees.aspx")
        ElseIf Roles.IsUserInRole(sUser, "Employee") Then
            Response.Redirect("~/AMSEmployee/AMSContacts.aspx")
        ElseIf Roles.IsUserInRole(sUser, "Contact") Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Customer/OrderEntry.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub
```

On the original page it properly redirects a Contact to http://www.xxxxx.com/Customer/OrderEntry.aspx. On the new page it the redirect goes to http://www.xxxxx/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fCustomer%2fOrderEntry.aspx. I replaced the domain name with xxxxx for the customer.

I can not figure out why the two pages behave differently. There is no login page at the root level of the site. Any help would be appreciated.

**A new problem.** I added the login page explicitly in the web.coonfig authentication node. That helped, but did not completely resolve the problem. Now when we go to the login page and enter a set of valid credentials I get a page not found message. If I then login in again with the same credentials the login is successful and continues to work until the browser is shut down, even when I log out and then log back in again. I can duplicate this behavior on the browsers of several different computers and in different browsers. I can not duplicate this on my development server.

Comment: Maybe you aren't actually logging the person in? So when they get redirected to `/Customer/OrderEntry.aspx`, that page is seeing the user as not authenticated, and it is correctly redirecting them to the old login page, since you haven't changed the configuration to reflect the new login page? Can you ensure an authentication cookie is getting set?

Comment: Did you check `form` tag `loginUrl` value in `web.config`?

Comment: I think rs hit it. I did not explicitly define the login page so apparently the name login worked. Added this tag and then put my redirect code in the on-load event on postback. Will try on the live server tonight after customers are off the site. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Could it have anything to do with where the web-app is hosted in IIS?
Hosting it as a website may give you different runtime results vs hosting it as a webapp within a website.

Specifically speaking: try looking into the Response.Redirect where you have the relative url (aspx path beginning with "~/". I have a feeling these two things are related (the two things being how it is hosted and this aspx path).